# LoadRunner and hidden elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, load-testing, stress-testing, loadrunner

I'm trying to write a LoadRunner script to stress my web application. However some of the links are displayed (they are initially hidden) using jQuery.

I have tried using the Web (Click and Script) protocol, which records all of my actions. However when I try replaying the script it cannot find the links that are dynamically displayed.

I also tried using Web (HTTP/HTML). However for some reason this protocol does not record any of my actions at all. Ajax (Click and Script) does the same thing.

I need to be able to support dynamic page elements (via jQuery) as well as AJAX pages/requests. Is this possible and if so what protocol/configuration should I use?

I'm running LoadRunner 9.52.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is both possible and common to use LoadRunner to test sites that are generated dynamically, from PHP to JSP to ASP to JQUERY.   Some of the mechanics differ from one solution to the next, but at the core there is a level of dynamic behavior related to session, state and business process that needs to be addressed in each case.

I guess the follow up questions are the following:

1. Why did you choose the protocols you have chosen?
2. Have you handled dynamic server provided elements in your business process through correlating for that information within your script?
3. Are you using LoadRunner on a fully supported platform for your version of LoadRunner and are you using it with appropriate credentials in the system? *Note: some 75% of 'that's odd' type of questions can be solved by dropping back to the system requirements and the user credentials*

Comment: 1. Well originally I wanted to use Web (Click and Script) because my application involves dynamic elements. I tested out the other protocols as more of a stab in the dark. 2. I don't really understand your second question. 3. I'm running Windows 7, IE 8, LoadRunner 9.52. Credentials aren't the problem.

Comment: (1)Truclient is the preferred model for dynamic client elements.  Dynamic server elements can simply use http (2) Handling dynamic server provided elements is a basic construct in performance testing tools and is the subject of 1/3 of the LoadRunner web virtual user training class (3) You must be running at least LoadRunner 11 to have Windows 7 support (32 bit only, Professional or higher, Admin credentials required.)

Comment: I'm not talking about dynamic server provided elements. I'm talking about DOM elements dynamically created using Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Truclient is the preferred method for dynamic client elements.  This is a LoadRunner 11 feature, which you will require for Windows 7 support.

Comment: Something to consider, you may be just fine with HTTP virtual users.   If all your client side code does is hide or display elements as needed but does not generate any additional server traffic on its own then you would likely be fine with just http virtual users and adjusting the submitted data for the dynamic elements associated with session, state, time and business process specific data elements.   If you have a full set of Asynch activity going on with the client which generates server calls in the background, then you need a client type like TruClient in LR 11.